# What is the correct visa for a spouse?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, spouses

I was refused for my standard visitor visa, to join my husband in the UK. We want to re-apply as a spouse but, when I try to create my application online, there is no spouse category. It asks reason for visit, type of visa, subtype of visa. Where do I find the right visa application?

Comment: You want to live with your husband permanently? If so, that's a question for [expatriates.stackexchange](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/); we only do short-term travel here. You'll want to tell them whether he's a UK citizen or what immigration status he has in the UK. Why did you apply for a _visitor_ visa if you weren't planning on just a short visit?

Comment: @ZachLipton the reverse situation may be topical for us,  see the paragraph beginning with "Conversely..." below :)

Comment: @GayotFow Yes, your answer is quite helpful regardless

Answer (score 5):

I can see the problem...

There are two portals to apply for a UK visa.  You have found the one for visitors and other types of visas that are issued for 6 months or less.

There is another portal for settlement visas, you can find it by following the links starting at [Visa4UK](https://www.visa4uk.fco.gov.uk/account/register) and creating an account.  You will know you have reached the right portal when you see a screen like this...

[image]

After the email confirmation is complete, you will eventually see some drop-downs, which you can select just like this...

[image]

After that, the program knows what to do.

Note that even though the drop-down label says "Reason for visit" and the correct response for you is "Settlement", which is not a visit category, this is an artefact from an earlier era and you can safely ignore it (it is not a trick question and the form is free from trick questions).

---

Conversely, people who have located the settlement portal and want to reach the VISITOR portal should follow the links from [Apply for a UK Visa](https://visas-immigration.service.gov.uk/product/uk-visit-visa).

---

They may harmonise the two portals at some point making this answer obsolete but I doubt it. Having two portals that do not link to each other makes the process more baroque, and they like that. So do not expect to see harmonisation soon.

Comment: Plus, it may involve different offices for approval in the backend - and, well, we all know how government loves efficiency :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response. It really a great help for us. So i will apply for settlement.. settlement..wife, which ive found it in the category. Thank you very much.